# Magento 1.9 Paypal checkout is stuck at Terms and Condition

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal

Need help please, looked all over the interweb and cannot find solution!

Problem: When i use Paypal checkout, it's stuck at Terms and Condition, when the customer checks the form box "I understand and accept these terms and condition" the Place Order button becomes disabled and won't be able to proceed with ordering.

Using Credit Card for checkout is fine and works ok. when i disable Terms and Condition on checkout, Paypal work ok too, but i need customers to agree with Terms and Condition.

I tried renaming paypal.xml and removing Paypal API Credentials, emptying Cache etc. but none works.

I attached screen capture of the error with element inspector..[image]

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors? check the console tab in firebug

Comment: Error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead
https://www.megsales-usa.com/js/prototype/prototype.js
Line 5878

Comment: That was the error that shows in Firebug, thanks @Aboodred1

Comment: how you're adding jQuery to your theme?

Comment: It's part of the theme that i got from Template Monster, as far as Magento itself, i had the hosting company install it for me and they said to contact the developer for this issue. Thanks again @Aboodred1

Comment: can you change the current theme/template to magento default theme and see if you get the same issue. It might be either jQuery issue or you're using outdated theme that is not fully compatible with magento v1.9

Comment: I changed the design theme to default and is still same error, the configuration scope has been on default config..

Comment: which Paypal option are you using in Magento payment methods?

Comment: Paypal payments pro and express

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so since you are using Paypal payment pro express, you'll not be able to proceed (click on Place order button).

> Paypal express is a checkout method and not a payment method.

If you want your customers to confirm Terms and Conditions checkbox before placing an order; then I recommend you to change Paypal pro express to Paypal Standard.

Comment: @MacIntosh if this solves your problem, feel free to mark it as acceptable answer.

Comment: It did not solve my problem, but still I thank you for your help!

Comment: @MacIntosh so you want to fix the issue using Paypal pro express? you don't want to use Paypal standard payment method?